# CSS - Fit container size to content, removing unused space

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a page for a project from FreeCodeCamp.
The problem is that I need to make a header for the page, and for some reason I'm getting some big gaps between my content and their respective containers.

I've already tried setting padding to zero, tweaking margins and things like that. Things like changing the "line-height" to 0 make it so the content take less space, but the container is kept almost unchanged.

I set a color for the background of each one of the objects that make up my content to check the area they are supposed to fill and compare it to the area of the container that surround them.

[Problem exemplification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYEa9.png)

Code below:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:300,400,700&display=swap');
html{
}
#header{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: grey;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
}
#header-logo{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: cyan;
}
#img-container{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 30px;
  height: 36px;
  background-color: pink;
}
#header-img{
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-top: -12px;
}
#header-text{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  background-color: pink;
}
#nav-bar{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: cyan;
}
#nav-list{  
  list-style: none;
  background-color: magenta;
}
.nav-item{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: pink;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.nav-item > a{
  wtext-decoration: none;
}
.nav-item:first-letter{
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
    </title>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <header id="header">
      <div id="header-logo">
        <div id="img-container">
          <image src="https://zapier-dev-files.s3.amazonaws.com/cli-platform/01368c80-24cc-415d-8262-df1c9382ea01" id="header-img">
          </image>
        </div>
        <h1 id="header-text">
          Penguino
        </h1>
      </div>
      <nav id="nav-bar">
        <ul id="nav-list">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#nav1" id="nav1" class="nav-link"> Home
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#nav2" id="nav2" class="nav-link"> Products
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#nav3" id="nav3" class="nav-link"> About
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#nav4" id="nav4" class="nav-link"> Contact
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
      
    </main>
    <footer>
    
    </footer>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is a link to my codepen:

https://codepen.io/Navarrox/pen/KKPGrxj

Hope someone can help me. Thanks!

EDIT: Removed the extra magenta space on the Navbar by setting padding-left to 0. I'd already done that before but for some reason I deleted the line before posting.

Comment: Not sure exactly what the problem is. The menu items are too far to the right?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I want to remove the unused space between the content and its container (indicated by the cyan color).

Comment: what you see is the default margin on a few element such as h1 , reset margin to 0 for h1 . To understand why that happens and how to avoid it, you can read : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing  forked pen https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/GRKPrRq

Comment: @G-Cyr so are you telling me that all boxes have a default margin value which I could change by setting it to 0? I tried that before, but to no avail. I noticed aswell that both your solution and jay surya's involve changing the display type from inline-block to flex. Is the block type of display forcing these margins or something like that?

Comment: i did not change any display, i just add margin:0 for h1 and ul to demonstrate the collapsing margin effect

Comment: @G-Cyr you're right, you didn't change it. It's just that the code you used from my Codepen was changed shortly after I posted it here, so it's is different from the one I posted in the body of the post itself.

Sorry for the confusion haha, I forgot I had changed the display to flex in my Codepen when I was fiddling around trying to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set header-logo container to `display:flex`, replace margin with padding for h1.
For right side nav, set `height:100%` to `ul` and `display:flex`.
Check this codepen : https://codepen.io/jsuryahyd/pen/jONXVJG

Comment: This is a good resource for flex-box - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following helps:

- For the understanding of page layout and the containing block. Click [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block)
- To understand more about block display, check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flow_Layout/Block_and_Inline_Layout_in_Normal_Flow)
- You can also check out CSS Grid [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)
- Comparison between grid and flexbox [here](https://css-tricks.com/quick-whats-the-difference-between-flexbox-and-grid/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to increase your width and height. Just manipulating it till it suits you. Otherwise, width: 100%;